# How to automatically connect letters into words?

Tags: strings, natural-language-processing

I would like to connect letters into meaningful words? E.g.

input:

```
T E ST IN G WE B A P P LIC AT IO N S
```

output:

```
TESTING WEB APPLICATIONS
```

- what kind of task is this? A task in NLP, or just some string operation?
  What kinds of NLP task(s) are involved?
- Are there software programs that I can use to do the job?
- What are some programming libraries that I can call to do the job?

note that: 
my original text not shown here is a mixture of space-separated letters and words, and are there software programs or programming libraries that can find out and take advantage of the existing words?

Comment: This almost sounds like a tool recommendation, which would be off-topic. If you want to write something like this yourself, you need a big list of valid words, and then we can talk about substring search algorithms. If you actually want the program to choose "meaningful" words instead of whatever comes up first in the list, that requires natural language processing, which is still a largely unsolved problem. Which of these issues are you actually seeking help for?

Comment: Is the first "issue" a method for solving the second "issue" (an NLP problem)? yes, I would like to learn what is on topic here.

Comment: This is language modeling. A language model takes a sequence of words and returns a score for how likely that phrase is in the language. An appropriate language model (such as a smoothed trigram) and a dynamic programming algorithm like Viterbi can make this relatively computationally efficient.

Considering taking a look at the first couple lectures of Michael Collins' NLP Coursera.

Comment: @chmullig: Are there software programs that I can use to do the job? What are some programming libraries that I can call to do the job? (note that: my original text not shown here is a mixture of space-separated letters and words, and are there software programs or programming libraries that can find out and take advantage of the existing words?)

Comment: You need to provide more context. Do you want all solutions? Is this intended to solve some kind of puzzle or is there more context (e.g. surrounding words) from a natural language application?

Comment: @RespawnedFluff: Context is [here](http://highered.mheducation.com/sites/dl/free/0078022126/1016997/Table_of_Contents.pdf). I extracted its text and got those separated letters.

Comment: @Tim: Well, Adobe's Reader has no problem finding the string "testing web applications" in there, so you are probably just using a bad/wrong tool for text extraction. I fear your question is classic example of the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)...

Comment: What tool do you recommend to use to extract text from pdf files? I am using `pdftotext` under Ubuntu? @RespawnedFluff

Comment: Your actual question is "what can I use to restore mangled text" which as @Ixrec mentions is off-topic. Even with the right tool you'd be stuck manually checking every parsed sentence for validity. Your actual problem is an issue with `pdftotext` which is also off-topic. It probably belongs on [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdftotext/hot).

Comment: I think this is the best example of [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) I've ever seen. We should add it to that meta thread.

Answer (score 23):

You definitely need NLP. For example:

```
EX P ER T S E XC H A NG E
```

may either mean

```
EXPERT SEX CHANGE
```

or

```
EXPERTS EXCHANGE
```

depending on context.

Comment: Can proof reading software such as `aspell` solve the problem somehow?

Comment: They are both spelled correctly, so, obviously not.

Comment: What is the kind of task(s) involved in my question called in NLP?

Comment: to understand the context. Even a human without context won't be able to find the correct spelling.

Comment: @lesto, even a human *with* context won't be able to find the correct spelling sometimes.

Comment: Hence why they added the hyphen. If you want some good wood, I recommend [penisland.net](http://penisland.net)

Comment: It's because of you and people like you that Experts Exchange had to get a new website URL. :-)

Comment: Well, you need NLP for the rare cases where this type of multiple solution/interpretation is possible, presuming only one solution is "right", but the OP says nothing of the sort; perhaps he wants all solutions, e.g. this is a puzzle? I think fundamentally the problem is combinatorial, selecting the "right" answer comes after that.

Comment: @RespawnedFluff, I would say "rare" is rather optimistic -- if you rely on manually fixing "rare" cases someone's going to be busy.  You might be able to say "rare" if you require grammatical correctness, but if anyone's built a grammar checker that's any good I've never seen it.

Comment: @Tim, `aspell` is merely a spell checker -- it's basically just checking whether a string is in a list of strings, i.e. there is no context.

Answer (score 11):

This problem is called [word segmentation](//stackoverflow.com/q/1781647/1157100) or text segmentation, and it has been [extensively studied](//www.google.com/search?q=word+segmentation+algorithm).

Note that in languages such as Chinese, Japanese, and Korean, all text in a sentence normally appears with no whitespace.  Word segmentation is therefore a prerequisite for machine interpretation of CJK text.

Comment: That's a somewhat unfortunate name although one can find some good resources with it, e.g. http://www.phontron.com/slides/nlp-programming-en-04-ws.pdf Another name for it is **tokenization [in/of unsegmented languages]** which seem to yield more sources e.g. http://comp.mq.edu.au/units/comp348/ch2.pdf or https://books.google.com/books?id=nK-QYHZ0-_gC&pg=PA15

Comment: Some people also called it word boundary detection. This is also a prerequisite for machine interpretation of speech (sound) for any language.

Answer (score 5):

Actually this is not an AI problem, this is pure programming question solved by dynamic programming.

If you simply want to connect the tokens into a list of correctly spelled words then you proceed as follows (Top down style dynamic programming):

```
public class Connector {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<String> tokens = new ArrayList<String>(); // input
        Connector connector = new Connector();

        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        List<String> ret = connector.connect(tokens);
    }

    Map<Integer, List<String>> cache;
    List<String> tokens;

    public List<String> connect(List<String> tokens) {
        this.cache = new HashMap<Integer, List<String>>();
        this.tokens = tokens;
        List<String> ret = connect(tokens, 0);
        return ret;
    }


    List<String> connect(List<String> tokens, int start) {
        if (cache.containsKey(start)) {
            return cache.get(start);
        } else {
            List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
            connectHelper(tokens, start, results);
            cache.put(start, results);
            return results;
        }
    }


    void connectHelper(List<String> tokens, int start, List<String> results) {
        int n = tokens.size();
        for(int i = start + 1; i < n; i++) {
            String part = concat(tokens, start, i);
            if (dictContains(part)) {
                List<String> restParts = connect(tokens, i);
                for(String oneRestPart : restParts) {
                    results.add(part + " " + oneRestPart);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    static private String concat(List<String> tokens, int low, int hi) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i = low; i < hi; i++) {
            sb.append(tokens.get(i));
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: In the example from [my answer](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/273290/1352), how does your algorithm decide which one of the two possible solutions is the correct one?

Comment: @JörgWMittag: Does it need to? The question doesn't specify that the software needs to produce correct result. Only meaningful results. So the correct answer to your answer would be to print both results.

Comment: @slebetman: I guess it depends on whether you interpret "meaningful" as "meaningful in context" or simply "individual meaningful words".

Comment: Thanks. Where is the part in the code that can recognize a  sequence of letters as a word? Does it need some human used dictionary?

Comment: @Tim. Yes, it's the dictContains(part) bit. It checks if the word exists in the dictionary. It's not shown how that's implemented. What's shown is how the parts are combined in various combinations and those combinations are checked against the dictionary.

Comment: @Jörg W Mittag If you want to choose one solution, you need to have a grammar (even crude one) and then define a corpus from which statistics can be drawn. The rest is about ranking using extracted stats.

Answer (score 2):

### The problem is called 'language modeling'

It is trivial to connect letters into *some* words by taking any dictionary (list of valid words) and finding a way that fits. However, in practice the main problem in this task usuall is finding the ***best*** words that fit those letters. Fortunately, this is a problem that others have as well - it occurs in, for example, speech recognition and thus is rather well researched and has resources and various ways to try and solve it. In this field, this problem is generally called *'language modeling'*.

### Statistical methods

The currently standard approach for this problem is to statistically evaluate the likelihood of each subfragment based on a large number of examples of how the language looks in real world. If we often see fragments like "... to therapist" and rarely see fragments like "... to the rapist" then we may assume that those letters should be merged together.

A good classic textbook descriptions are available in Speech and Language Processing by Dan Jurafsky and Jim Martin (chapter 6 in the 1st edition, chapter 4 in the 2nd edition) and  Foundations of Statistical Natural Language Processing by Chris Manning and Hinrich Schütze (chapter 6).

An often used library for doing language modeling is SRILM - http://www.speech.sri.com/projects/srilm/manpages/ and I believe that projects such as python NLTK (http://www.nltk.org/) also have tools for that.  In any case, the particular model (weights of word combinations) is different for each language and domain, so this may be something that you have to adapt yourself.